# The implied meaning of "improve"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From this sentence,

> As an initial estimate I think we'll **be looking at** **April** **to
>   improve** the existing system but for a new system it would take at
>   least nine months.

Does it mean that the speaker will **finish** making the existing system **completely** better in April OR that he is going to **begin** improving the existing system in April and it will be **finished sometime later**?

To sum up, my question is what really is the meaning of the word "improve" used in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the **sentence** you should be **focusing** on is...

> "... we will be looking **at** April..."

In this context, **improve** would to make the **existing system better** or more **efficient**. The way this is **worded** makes it sound like it will be **started to be improved on April**, and be more **efficient** at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is merely to improve the system, we're looking at an April *delivery date*; a new system would take nine months at least.

**to be looking at** is an informal way of saying "expecting, projecting, anticipating"

The projection can be time or cost, or even the details.

> How much to repair the hail-storm damage to the roof?
>   -- We're looking at $6,000.
>   Why so much?
>   --Well, you're looking at demolition, a dumpster, roofing materials, labor to install the new shingles, etc.
>   When can you do the job?
>   -- We're backed up. We're looking at six weeks, at the earliest.